# Manually telling EXT4 about bad sectors?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, ext4, badblocks

The drive is currently in NTFS. After running `chkdsk` for hours, I have found the locations of bad sectors (below). I want to reformat the disk in EXT4. I have heard that EXT4 has some sort of metadata to mark bad sectors, and there is a utility for that, but I do not want to run the test for hours again. Can I just directly tell EXT4 about the bad sector locations below that I have already found by `chkdsk`?

```
Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x280036f1000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x280036fb000 for 0x1000 bytes.


Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x280cb987000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x280cb993000 for 0x1000 bytes.


Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x280dbdc2000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x280dbdc4000 for 0x1000 bytes.


Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x2835d5bb000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x2835d5c0000 for 0x1000 bytes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "badblocks" command together with e2fsck to specify a list of bad disk blocks to the filesystem.

As others have commented, that is not great, because that means your disk is on the verge of increasing failure. Also, because this is normally handled at the drive level today, this badblocks code is rarely used these days.

Answer (score 4):

**This is serious: Make a backup of your data and throw away that hard drive.** Until you can make that backup, don't use the drive; disconnect it.

There's a direct way to tell ext4 which sectors are bad when you make the file system, using the `-L` when making the file system. *I will not describe it here in more detail, because it's honestly a terrible idea;* you should nevertheless feel free to research it yourself.

The fact that it took hours to find these errors means that your hard drive takes a long time in regular operations in more places than these already failing locations. This means there's more places that are about to fail. This drive is *losing data*, it's **not**

> these places are broken and the rest of the drive is somewhat OK

It's

> this drive is broken, but right now most of it is, with a lot of effort, still readable; it *looks* correct, but there's no way of knowing whether it *is* correct. The accessibility might change any second for the worse.

Formatting the partition with EXT4 and copying any new data on it will put extended stress on the device. More things will fail.

This drive is done. It's not fit for storage any more. Sorry. Throw it away. There's literally no data that is useful when it's wrong in unknown locations or might not be readable when you need it.

Comment: I think it took hours because the drive is big (3TB). I am not going to store important data on it, but things that I can lose. I don't get just by the `-L`. How can I specify the locations of bad sectors?

Comment: How is "*I will not describe it here in more detail, because it's honestly a terrible idea*" ambiguous? Sorry, I will not describe it in any more detail; please don't ask. Seriously, re-read my last sentence: "There's literally no data that is useful when it's wrong in unknown locations or might not be readable when you need it."

Comment: Ditto.  You can buy a good 3 Tb HDD for less than a hundred bucks nowadays.  Throw it away.

Comment: I don't like this consumer's mentality of buying new stuff when something has become a bit weared down. First, you didn't describe how do define that threshold when the drive is in critical state (hours of operation, percentage of bad blocks, etc?). Second, just for educational purposes you could answer the question.

Comment: It's not a "bit worn down", it's broken. What is described in the question is **far** beyond the threshold of being critical. Get rid of it. I answered the question, for all educational purposes. There's no educational value in using something that loses your data. Literally, the right education there is: throw it away, it's broken beyond usability.

Answer (score 4):

About 20-25 years ago, before disks had internal defect management, it made sense for the filesystem to do block level defect management and add blocks to bad block lists both while formatting and as the drive ages.

Modern disks all have SMART defect management (or the NVME equivalent) and automatically replace bad blocks with good blocks.   Typically writing to a bad block is enough to trigger it to be repaired by replacing with a good block.

If your disk has large numbers of bad blocks, it means it has run out of replacement blocks.  Considering the large number of replacement blocks it starts with, this probably means that the disk is mechanically failing (there's probably debris floating around inside causing more damage), and it is probably close to complete catastrophic failure.

You can verify this by using the `smartctl -a` command on the device.  Near the top, it should indicate the drive health, and near the bottom it includes a list of block errors.  If it either indicates the disk is failing or you see block error reports, likely the disk is failing.  If it says it is ok, you should run a test (either `-t long` or `-t short`) and after waiting (typically 2 min for short, multiple hours for long), check again and look for the test results.

If the drive passes a long test, it is probably still OK to use, and possibly you just need to trigger some writes to the bad sectors to try to get them repaired.

Comment: I only turned it on yesterday for the first time in years. How much "Replacement blocks" does a HDD have, anyway? Shouldn't it have at least a few megabytes, given the fact that the disk sizes is in terabytes? Chkdsk results say "16KB in bad sectors". Unless the disk may catche fire or something, I don't know why I should not continue to use it for non important files of which I am willing to take the risk of losing. CrystalInfo says raw values of pending sectors / uncorrectable sectors are 20/20.

Comment: There's no way to know when it will fail without running a long test.  After a long test, you should know if it is going to fail in weeks or not for a while.  The number of replacement blocks is some percentage of the drive size.  The real question here is, are these unrepaired blocks that can be repaired by writing to them, or is the disk out of replacement blocks.

Comment: Well, again, the files are "losable". If the degradation is gradual, like unreadable sectors become increasing 1GB per day (it would still take 8 years until the disk becomes completely useless) I think I could determine the point I would stop using it. The only case that could hurt (but not devastate) me a little bit is the disk suddenly one day becoming completely unreadable (all files are gone at once).

Comment: If the disk has been sitting on a shelf for a while, it could be the magnetic domains decayed to make the blocks bad and rewriting them might fix them.  However, if it's got debris floating around inside, the whole thing could die in a few weeks or a few hours.  Just do a SMART long test.  If it passes, it's reliable.  If you don't test it and it's bad, you might spend more time copying data onto it than it lasts after the copy.